# How can I make a SQL temp table with primary key and auto-incrementing field?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, temp-tables

What am I missing here?
I'm trying to get the `ID` field to be the primary key and auto increment so that I don't need to insert it explicitly.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
AssignedTo NVARCHAR(100),
AltBusinessSeverity NVARCHAR(100),
DefectCount int
);

insert into #tmp 
select 'user','high',5 union all
select 'user','med',4


select * from #tmp
```

I get an error with this saying:

> Insert Error: Column name or number of
>   supplied values does not match table
>   definition.

Comment: Don't be lazy, specify the columns you want to insert.  You will appreciate this later

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You are just missing the words "primary key" as far as I can see to meet your specified objective.

For your other columns it's best to explicitly define whether they should be `NULL` or `NOT NULL` though so you are not relying on the `ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON` setting.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) primary key ,
AssignedTo NVARCHAR(100),
AltBusinessSeverity NVARCHAR(100),
DefectCount int
);

insert into #tmp 
select 'user','high',5 union all
select 'user','med',4


select * from #tmp
```

Comment: PK shouldn't be necessary for an identity column.

Comment: @Sam - He specifies he wants it as the PK. Why do you say it shouldn't be necessary anyway? He might well want the unique constraint enforcement, and clustered index that comes with defining it as PK.

Comment: i dont want dups, so i thought primary key would be perfect. i want to use it later in a while loop

Comment: @kacalapy - Try running `DROP TABLE #tmp` I suspect that you may have an old version messing things up.

Comment: thanks martin, i did have an old #tmp, droped it and its fine now... should i use #tmp or @tmp ?

Comment: Probably `@tmp` - That is slightly lower overhead in terms of recompilations and logging. The trade off is that statistics aren't maintained for them so sometimes you can end up with sub optimal plans when using them in a join. However I think it will recognise even without statistics that a select on `id` will return a maximum of 1 row because of the unique constraint.

Comment: @Martin - The PK is not necessary for the identity insert to work and that is the problem he encountering.

Comment: @Sam - Don't know about you but I'm answering the following question `how can i make a sql temp table with primary key and autoincrmenting field?` You appear to be answering half of it!

Answer (score 10):

you dont insert into identity fields.  You need to specify the field names and use the Values clause

```
insert into #tmp (AssignedTo, field2, field3) values (value, value, value)
```

If you use do a `insert into... select field field field`
it will insert the first field into that identity field and will bomb

Answer (score 10):

If you're just doing some quick and dirty temporary work, you can also skip typing out an explicit CREATE TABLE statement and just make the temp table with a SELECT...INTO and include an Identity field in the select list.

```
select IDENTITY(int, 1, 1) as ROW_ID,
       Name
into #tmp
from (select 'Bob' as Name union all
      select 'Susan' as Name union all
      select 'Alice' as Name) some_data

select *
from #tmp
```